# How does Slither.io resolve head-on collisions?

Tags: slither.io

In Slither.io, whenever I run into another snake head on, I seem to lose the exchange and die while my opponent lives on. It's most apparent when there is a fresh kill and we're both racing (boosting) from opposite ends of the former snake until we inevitably meet in the middle.

I'm sure this is just a bit of confirmation bias, but when two snakes run into each other head on, how does the game determine which one survives and which one becomes snake food?

<sub>*For anyone not familiar with this online game: [slither.io](http://slither.io) is a large-field, multi-player game where you move your "snake" around trying to avoid running into others while causing others to run into you.*</sub>

Comment: If I had to guess it is based on which snake moves first. Which snake moves first? Well... maybe it is the one that was created first. Or they get a random id, and they are enumerated by id. I am mostly just guessing here.

Answer (score 3):

For the most part, head on collisions seem to be random. For many occurrences, the boosting snake seems to have the advantage. The mechanics of deciding who wins in a head on collision have not been fully figured out yet, but the mass definitely had nothing to do with it.

> Here's a great debate about some people who did tests on [Reddit](https://reddit.com/r/Slitherio/comments/4dex25/how_the_hell_to_headon_collisions_work/?ref=readnext).
>
> Addition:

When you are boosting the game predicts where you will be next, so you could be going a different way but you still die when they did not run in front of you. This is one of the flaws of the game, so if you are boosting the game will assume when your in contact, you've already past them, so they will be killed. If you are both boosting, it would end out the same as if neither of you are boosting, resulting it as random.

Comment: To clarify, the cases I'm referring to are when *both* snakes are boosting. I clarified my question.

Comment: @RobertCartaino With boosting there is a glitch... Let me clarify my answer...

Comment: @RobertCartaino there, I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I think that it actually works like this as the example below.

Snake A's mass is 3k, while Snake B's mass is 5k. They both have a head-on collision, and Snake B survived because his mass is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the larger snake (more mass) wins in a head-on collision.